# Copying directories recursively in tcl

Tags: file-io, tcl

When I tried copying a directory recursively to another directory I am getting an error message. If foo is my source and bar is my target directory, I am getting error as

```
"can't overwrite file "bar/foo" with directory "foo"
```

and my tcl command is

```
file mkdir "bar"
file copy -force  ./foo bar
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure `foo` isn't somehow accidentally a file, _like perhaps a symbolic link_?

Comment: The only way I ran into this same error is when *bar* is actually a file, or a link (hard or symbolic).

Comment: I am getting this error : can't overwrite file "bar/foo" with directory "foo"

Comment: I'm guessing that you're somehow copying things into or over themselves. That can go quite thoroughly wrong; don't do it.

Comment: Which exactly error are you getting? `can't overwrite file "foo" with directory "bar"` or `"can't overwrite file "bar/foo" with directory "foo"`? The second one actually tells you that there is `foo` inside `bar`.

Comment: I am getting the second mentioned error.. (updated in my question). I don't find any file in my target directory

Comment: If you're still having trouble, would you do an `ls -al` in all relevant directories _before_ running the Tcl commands, and post the results?

Answer (score 1):

You can use exec:

```
exec cp -f ./foo bar
```

It always works for me.

Comment: Don't forget to use the `-r` flag to get a recursive copy. I just struggled the same issue with tcl and your simple approach is the one which works.

Comment: A tcl only version would be better.